# Angular dynamic controls, @ngrx/store, and one-way data-binding: control is never marked 'dirty'

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, ngrx-store

I am using `@ngrx/store` and doing one-way data-binding.

I have a dumb component that gets a list of values as `@Input()`.
Based on this list, I create a `FormArray` of `FormControl`s to allow user input. I do this in `ngOnChanges` if my `SimpleChanges` has provided a new value for the list of values.

Due to one-way-data-binding, each time the user inputs a character, an action is dispatched to the store and the list of values comes through `ngOnChanges` again. 
Since the `FormArray` is recreated, it does not preserve the `dirty` and `pristine` attributes. They get reset.

I am using `trackBy`.

The value of the `dirty` attribute is important to me, as I use it to decide whether to show the validation alert or not.

Any idea how to get around the problem?

I have a plunker that shows the issue. I have used a BehaviorSubject to fake out `@ngrx/store`. Please try inputing values in any of the input controls and observe the `dirty` and `pristine` as shown: https://plnkr.co/edit/xZmU4ww8Y9PEgFOCOOw4?p=info